# How to swap object again in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have create the game in which object is swapping it's position with empty game object. problem occur when i click first time on the object it swap.,but when i click again on same object it does not swap it's position. what am i doing wrong..??please help

**board.cs**

```
void Start () {

       for(int a=GridHeight;a>0;a--){
         for(int b=0;b<GridWidth;b++)
       {

          GameObject g =  Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 ( b,a, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
          //g.AddComponent("GUIText");
          //g.guiText.text = y.ToString();
          g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;


          gemComponent = g.GetComponent<Gem>();
          gems.Add(gemComponent);

          if(a==1 && b==3)
          { 
              gemComponent.cube.renderer.enabled = false;
          }

       }
       gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (-2.5f, -2.5f, 0);



    }
public void SwapGem(Gem gem1)
    {

       gem1start = gem1.transform.position;
       gem1end = gemComponent.transform.position;
       if (gemComponent.IsNeighbourWith(gem1))
       {
                 gem2start = gem1end;
                 gem2end = gem1start;
                 gem1.transform.position = gem2start;
                 gemComponent.transform.position = gem2end;

          }

       for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++) {

         if(gems[i].transform.position != gems[randomIndex].transform.position)
         {
          print ("not");
         }else{
          //Application.LoadLevel("level02");
          print ("yes");
         }

          }
    }
```

**Feeler.cs**

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
       //owner.RemoveNeighbor(c.GetComponent<Gem>());
                 if (c.tag == "Gem") {

                    owner.AddNeighbor(c.GetComponent<Gem> ());

          }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider c)
    {
       if(c.tag =="Gem")
       {
         owner.RemoveNeighbor(c.GetComponent<Gem>());


       }
}
```

**Gems.cs**

```
public void AddNeighbor(Gem g)
    {    
          if (!Neighbors.Contains (g)) {
                 Neighbors.Add (g);
       } 
       }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {

          if (!GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().isSwapping) {
                 GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().SwapGem (this);

          }

    }

       public void RemoveNeighbor(Gem g)
       {

       Neighbors.Remove(g);

       }
```

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Comment: Maybe is your SwapGem() method finished it doesn't set isSwapping to false?

Comment: @  Verv OnTriggerExit the clicked objects remove their neighbours as a result empty object and gameobject not remain neigbhours. i am unable to solve this.how they become neighbours to one another on click with OnTriggerEnter as they were in intial state